# Firebase Key/Value access not working

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, reactfire

I have the following data setup in firebase.

```
{ 
  "data": {
    "lava14mod1":"down",
    "lava14mod2":"up"
  }
}
```

I'm able to access it in my React app. But I can only access it as a (key,value) pair combined as one string.

I cannot access the key or value **separately** using,

```
<li>{this.state.data[0]['.key']}</li>
```

I'm getting this error,

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '.key' of undefined

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_currentElement' of null
```

Here's the full code, running on plunker, (without the error line)

http://plnkr.co/edit/zjFKsYAzfYrzGmedVEV6?p=preview

I've been pouring through the docs and still can't figure this out. I'm following the data structure shown in firebase docs,

```
[
  {
    ".key": "-Jtjl482BaXBCI7brMT8",
    ".value": 100
  },
  {
    ".key": "-Jtjl6tmqjNeAnQvyD4l",
    "first": "Fred"
    "last": "Flintstone"
  },
  {
    ".key": "-JtjlAXoQ3VAoNiJcka9",
    ".value": "foo"
  }
]
```

[Firebase documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/react/api.html)

Is there some problem with my syntax? How do I access the key or value separately?
Thank you so much.

Comment: Screenshots of textual content (JSON, error messages, code, documentation) are no substitute for the real thing. To try to reproduce the behavior you're having, I'd have to retype the data and code. Instead of screenshots, include the actual text. A (additional) link to the plunkr would be great too, since that would remove the need for me (or others looking to help) to set up the reproduction.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/zjFKsYAzfYrzGmedVEV6?p=preview

Comment: thx for the response! 
here's the plunker link. I thought of adding it earlier, but stackoverflow, complains about not having a code snippet.

Comment: i think i'm missing something really obvious.

Comment: Thanks for that link. But **also** include the minimal **text** of the information in your question. I've just replaced your first screenshot with the JSON that was in it. Now you do the others.

Comment: Aside from that the plunkr works for me and shows `local var, lava14mod1`

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen
for json local variable, it works. 

I'm trying to do the same thing when querying firebase data.
i'm not able to get the key separately for that.

Comment: Have you solved this?

Comment: No i have not solved this.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting that error because the `this.state.data` object does not have the keys you're trying to access in `render`.

This is easy to see if you simply put a `console.log(this.state.data)` in `render`. Doing so gives me something like this in the console:

```
> []
> [Object]
> [Object, Object]
> [Object, Object, Object]
```

So, `render` is being called four different times, once each time that `this.state.data` is being updated with a new key. But, in your `render`, you don't consider the fact that keys `[0]` and `[1]` might not exist - you try to access them without checking them first.

Now I'm not sure exactly why your `state` is being updated piecemeal, but it probably has something to do with the ReactFireMixin which I have no experience with. Fetching form Firebase is clearly an asynchronous action (since you have to grab data from the cloud) so you need to make accommodations for that.

The most straightforward fix is simply checking to make sure that the key you want to access actually exists on an object before you try to access it (which is a good practice in most cases to avoid exactly this kind of error!)

```
render: function() {
    return (
        <div>

          from firebase,
          {this.state.data ? <li>{this.state.data}</li> : undefined}
          {this.state.data && this.state.data[0] && this.state.data[0][".key"] ? <li>{this.state.data[0][".key"]}</li> : undefined}
          {this.state.data && this.state.data[1] && this.state.data[1][".key"] ? <li>{this.state.data[1][".key"]}</li> : undefined}

          local var,
          <li>{data2[0]['.key']}</li>


        </div>
    );
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/7XXaOIQCQcyGneqEqa88?p=preview

An even better solution would be to use `Array.map` to convert whatever array `this.state.data` is at the time directly into some kind of list. This is a very common pattern in React applications because you'll often keep lists of data as arrays and then want to display it dynamically.

```
render: function() {
    return (
        <div>

          from firebase,
          {this.state.data.map(function(ea){return <li>Key: <strong>{ea[".key"]}</strong>, Value: <strong>{ea[".value"]}</strong></li>})}

          local var,
          <li>{data2[0]['.key']}</li>


        </div>
    );
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/b1j10M1i635hvapFxZbG?p=preview

[More about `Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)